# render partial html in component in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

In angular2 I am trying to render HTML from component ts file, this partial HTML can vary a lot and therefore must be defined by the user from a component. In the plunker that I am posting, currently I am using  `<span [innerHTML]="test.template"></span>` where test.template is another piece of HTML which can be ,, or

with model value. How can I achieve thais functionality?

[PlunkerLink](https://plnkr.co/edit/RZY6yULlVoWqVNefl5i5?p=preview)

The reason why I am trying to achieve this is because we are using primeng component and there datatable uses html base template which I want to provide via component ts file. Please have a look primeng datatable templating [PrimengDatatableTemplating](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating)

Answer (score 0):

Your example will work if you will pass just HTML in `[innerHTML]`.
By "just HTML" I mean HTML without Angular syntax in it like you did here:

```
test = {
    template:this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<span [innerHTML]="gg"></span>')
}
```

Instead of passing `'<span [innerHTML]="gg"></span>'` you can pass `<span>gg</span>` and this should work.

If this is not sufficient for your needs, consider using [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) but it can be very tricky to get expected functionality out of it.

Comment: it will print gg only but I want to display component variable where gg is defined as variable in component with some value in it